# Django - How to properly override model's delete() method to update (soft delete) instead of delete

Tags: python, django

My database design requires to set "deleted" flag on table row when a row is deleted, instead of actually deleting a row. I am using formsets that call model's delete() function when an object is marked for deletion. This means I need to override model's delete function. Using signals is not an option.

My question is how do I properly override it to do update instead of delete. I looked at models.Model.delete function and it does some complex stuff using django.db.models.deletion.Collector class. The Collector can delete and also update values. I was able to override delete method to update only as following:

```
class CustomerInfo(models.Model):
  ...
  def delete(self, using=None):        
    collector = Collector(using=using)
    collector.add_field_update(self._meta.get_field('deleted'), True, [self])
    collector.delete()
```

But I am not sure if this is the proper way to do it. Alternatively I can override it as following.

```
def delete(self, using=None):
    self.deleted = True
    self.save()
```

Both approaches work, but I am not sure which is the correct one.

Comment: Note that neither of these will have any effect if you do `CustomerInfo.objects.all().delete()`.

Comment: If you are not deleting the Model instance, but just updating some info, then I think you should not use the delete() method, unless you have no other way to get through this. I would create a method on the Model "soft_delete" that just updated the "deleted" atribute, like you are doing in the 2nd snippet, which BTW does not need the variable using. Just add a method to model and call it when needed in views or forms.

Comment: http://terrarum.net/development/soft-deleting-with-django.html

Comment: @dm03514
seems like a good instruction except for the comment about bulk delete as DanielRoseman also mentioned above. If that's not a problem that seems like a good one.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza: Good idea but as I mentioned I am using formsets and they use delete() function AFAIK

Comment: @dm03514: Great find. This should be an answer. The only problem I see with this is unintended saving of other changed fields when delete() is called.

Comment: would using similar code to that used by the `commit=False` parameter on `save()` work?: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py